# What's the advantage of naming every React component 'index.jsx'?

Tags: reactjs

I can see in many tutorials, code examples etc, lots of people just call every component 'index.jsx'. I still kind of assume it's best practice, so I always start my projects doing this, but quickly become really frustrated with it and swap back to something more sane.

I understand you don't need to write the name twice in the import, e.g `import ThisThing` rather than `import ThisThing/ThisThing`, but doesn't every single console log, editor tab title etc etc all having the same name make it impossible to debug or work with?

Comment: did the answer help you?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the lack of response @SharpCode! Kind of - I'm only using one default export per file, so I get what you mean but in my case I'm still not too clear on why I'd continue calling everything 'index.jsx'. Makes using any IDE or debug console kinda difficult, cause everything has the same name, y'know?

Answer (score 3):

So if you have index.jsx like so.

> src/containers/login/index.jsx

```
export function speak () {
  return 'speak'
}

export default function yell () {
  return 'yell'
}
```

then to import from say

> src/index.jsx

```
import yell, { speak } from './containers/login
```

You don't have to specifiy the index like `import yell, { speak } from ./containers/login`

But if you find your project has folders some of which might have 5+ components in them then a common practice is to export them all in a index.js file and then you can import them appropriately the same way without having to specify the file name.

So say I have `Speak.jsx`, `Clap.jsx` and `Jump.jsx` in a folder called `components`. Then I would also add an `index.js` folder with the following.

```
export { Speak } from './Speak'
export { Clap } from './Clap'
export { Jump } from './Jump'
```

and then to import depending on how many I need you can do any of the following.

```
import { Speak, Clap } from './src/components'
// or
import { Jump } from './src/components'
```

> you do not require the curly braces for default exports

There can only be one default export per file if you do go down that path.

Here is a much better and [in-depth tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f)